# Is it possible to mix static, multi-threaded, DLL libraries in one project?

Tags: dll, linker, shared-libraries

Is it possible to use distinct libraries A, B, C in the same project in Visual Studio, where A is a static library, B is multi-threaded and C is a multi-threaded DLL? Or do they all have to be the same type for a single .exe output?

Edit: Sorry, A is a single-threaded static library. B is a multi-threaded static library, C is a multi-threaded DLL. (I guess A and B are the same from the linker's point of view?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about libraries compiler with different CRT linking type(static, dll)?
If yes, then it's impossible.

Comment: Nothing to do with CRT. These are your average libraries

Comment: As one library is single and other multi threaded then they are linked with different CRTs even if everything else is the same - so you need to know which CRTs each one has - if C++ then will definitely matter if C then depemds on what functions are used

Comment: Ahh okay. The jigsaw piece has dropped into place a little...
Does this only matter for C/C++? For instance I have FORTRAN libraries that are either DLLs or static.

Answer (score 14):

You can freely mix static and dynamic libraries, so long as they all use the same run-time libs.

In Properties -> General -> Configuration Type -> set this to Static Library or Dynamic Library for the libraries A and B you want to static or dynamic.

In Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> Every library which will be linked together must use the *same* run-time library, for example Multi-Threaded Debug DLL.

Thus you could do:
A - Config Type: Static Library. Runtime Lib: Multi-threaded Debug DLL. (yes this is ok)
B - Config Type: Dynamic Library. Runtime Lib: Multi-threaded Debug DLL

These two libs could be linked into the same exe.

Comment: This answer is more complete than the accepted answer I guess. As long as the `A` and `B` are compiled with the same runtime libraries, they can be mixed.

Comment: Are there any downsides or risks to using the multi-threaded debug DLL with a static library like we do here with A?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what B is but the general idea is yes.

A will get compiled directly into the exe
B Not sure about what this one is
C Yes, functions within this library will be linked at runtime.